# OpenVPN Unable to Connect VPN Server using C#

Tags: c#, .net, vpn, desktop-application, openvpn

I am trying to connect VPN Server using OpenVPN Community from my Desktop Application Developed in C#. The code was working fine and suddenly I am getting below error when connection is established.

[image: Error]

Here is the code that was working earlier but not now.

```
string OpenVpnLocation = Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem ? @"C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin\openvpn.exe" : @"C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin\openvpn.exe";

Process process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    //WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
    FileName = OpenVpnLocation,
    Arguments = "--config server.ovpn --auth-user-pass ovpnpass.txt",
    Verb = "runas"
};
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

As per the error logs I understood that, route is already created and from this code it is creating another route, which throws an error, if so, then is there any way to handle it from C# code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to work with powershell and then back to the console. No way to catch this on C#

Comment: any suggestions how can I delete or close this route from powershell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before connecting to OpenVPN, kill the openvpn.exe and it is working fine.

```
Process process1 = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo1 = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
    FileName = "cmd.exe",
    Arguments = "taskkill.exe /F /IM openvpn.exe",
    Verb = "runas",
    UseShellExecute = true
};
process1.StartInfo = startInfo1;
process1.Start();
```